# Python 2.7.10 - Can not print using print. SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-2.7

I am learning Python from "Learn Python the Hard Way"

I am just running the first Print Hello World Program and getting a syntax error.

Here is my code for Hello World:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print “Hello World”
```

And here is the terminal :

```
Rahuls-MacBook-Pro:python Rahul$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  6 2017, 23:53:20) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "Hello World"
Hello World
>>> quit()
Rahuls-MacBook-Pro:python Rahul$ python hell.py
  File "hell.py", line 3
    print “Hello World”
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Rahuls-MacBook-Pro:python Rahul$
```

I have used the print() function alternative but it is not working. I get the output if I use arithmetic operation such as print(2+2). But it doesn't work if I use print("Hello World")

Please, can anyone tell, where I am wrong? 
Thank you.

Comment: Note you're using curly quotation marks (whatever you used to edit your hell.py is probably converting them automatically as you type.) You need straight quotation marks.

Comment: You *copied* the code from the site? You should write it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`“`, `”`, and `"` are all different characters. From those, only `"` can be used to quote string literals in Python.

Comment: Only `"`? What about `'`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Only `"` out of the 3 characters I listed.

Comment: I know. Fixed it ;)